# Images are not being displayed in my angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-flex-layout

Earlier it was giving an error that my typescript version("typescript": "~3.4.3") and flex version and not compatible with each other so i changed my flex version to the latest one(ie `"@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27"`). Now there is no error on compilation as well as console but still my images are not being displayed. This is my html code.

```html
<div class="container"
    fxLayout="column"
    fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <mat-list fxFlex>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
            <img matListAvatar src="{{dish.image}}" alt={{dish.name}}>
            <h1 matLine>{{dish.name}</h1>
            <p matLine><span>{{dish.description}}</span></p>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
    }
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-list-z2hpbq?embed=1&file=app/list-selection-example.html)**

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <mat-list fxFlex>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
            <img matListAvatar [src]="dish.image" [attr.alt]="dish.name">
            <h1 matLine>{{dish.name}}</h1>
            <p matLine><span>{{dish.description}}</span></p>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct because when you have array of objects you need to bind the src with [square] brackets.